# DataGrid CellStyle Setters with Freezable StaticRecource

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I wanted to set the command of a button in a WPF datagrid with a setter. But it seems that the DP property `CommandProperty` gets ovewritten with its default value `null` after I returned a copy in 
`CreateInstanceCore()`, so the original command gets lost.

If I bind the `StaticResource` directly it works without problems.
Is there a way to stop that behavior or another solution?

```
public class ResourceCommand : Freezable, ICommand {

    public ICommand Command {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Command.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ResourceCommand), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, CommandPropertyChangedCallback));


    static void CommandPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        ResourceCommand resourceCommand = (ResourceCommand)d;
        int h = resourceCommand.GetHashCode();
        if (e.OldValue != null)
            ((ICommand)e.OldValue).CanExecuteChanged -= resourceCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged;
        if (e.NewValue != null)
            ((ICommand)e.NewValue).CanExecuteChanged += resourceCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged;
    }

    #region ICommand Member

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
        if (Command == null)
            return false;
        return Command.CanExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    void OnCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
            CanExecuteChanged(sender, e);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) {
        Command.Execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() {
        ResourceCommand ResourceCommand = new ResourceCommand();
        ResourceCommand.Command = Command;
        return ResourceCommand;
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ResourceCommand x:Key="FirstCommand"  Command="{Binding FirstCommand}" />
    <local:ResourceCommand x:Key="SecondCommand"  Command="{Binding SecondCommand}" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Click me">
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Button">
                                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{StaticResource FirstCommand}" />
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you define your resource commands like this:

```
<local:ResourceCommand x:Key="FirstCommand" Command="{Binding FirstCommand}" x:Shared="False"/>
```

Using this technique you can even throw not-implemented in `CreateInstanceCore` and so you'll just be using `Freezable` to enable data binding.

Comment: 1. Button outside of a DataGrid and Command binds without style:
  Works. But worked before, too.
2. Button outside of a DataGrid and Command setting with style setter:
  Doesn't work. Calls CreateInstanceCore().
2. Button within a DataGrid and Command binds without style or with setting Command over style:
  Doesn't work. Calls CreateInstanceCore().

Comment: Using `x:Shared="False"` should prevent it from ever being cloned.  I tested 1. and 2.  Inside a `DataGrid` the `DataContext` will be different so make sure you have a command there because the binding as written is always relative to the data context of the element it is assigned to.

Comment: So it will bind the command to the item instead of the `DataContext` of the window? If yes, is there a way to bind to the `DataContext` of my window? Doesn't `x:Shared="false"` make the opposite and let it clone all the time?

Comment: You can bind to a named element as with any other data binding, e.g. `{Binding DataContext.FirstCommand, ElementName=window}`.  Things that are not `Freezable` can use `"x:Shared="False"` and still get copied because the copying is not using the `Freezable` cloning mechanism.  It creates a new resource from the XAML tree.

Comment: But the child items of the `DataGrid` are not in the visual tree so it won't be able to find the window. That's why I tryed to use that work around over binding to a static recource. I hoped that it saves a reference to my command of the datacontext of my window, which I would be able to share. As long that worked, till i tried to set the command over style setter instead of binding directly.

Comment: Sounds like you could use `ElementSpy`: http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/enable-elementname-bindings-with-elementspy/